BPNM Library Angular dynamic CSS
I'm using Bpmn library for a diagram.
I need to hide this palette on the diagram view...
so in the TypeScript file I did a @viewChild for that element and tried to add css dynamically to hide it.
    @ViewChild('djs-palette-entries') actionsPalette: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>
   
    togglePalette(){
 
        const paletteEntries = this.actionsPalette.nativeElement
 
            if (paletteEntries) {
                if (this.showPaletteEntries) {
                    this.renderer.setStyle(paletteEntries, 'display', 'block');
                } else {
                    this.renderer.setStyle(paletteEntries, 'display', 'none');
                }
            }
 
    }

it happens that this element 'djs-palette-entries' is generated from the BPMN library and not visible on the html ...
The code is not working, how could I hide this element dinamically, what would be the best aaproach?
Tried @ViewChild and expected it to be hidden

If it's added dynamically by 3rd party library, then simply query it as a DOM element on the component, assign it to this.actionsPalette in ngAfterViewInit, and then toggle it:
constructor(
  private el: ElementRef
  ) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.actionsPalette = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.djs-palette-entries');
    console.log('actionsPalette', this.actionsPalette);
  }

  togglePalette() {

    if (this.showPaletteEntries) {
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.actionsPalette, 'display', 'block');
    } else {
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.actionsPalette, 'display', 'none');
    }
    
  }

